# Como converter o encoding do response de uma requisição axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, axios, back-end

O json de resposta da requisição está retornando caracteres inválidos (acentuação).

```
// Express
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// axios
const axios = require('axios');

// Rotas - Página Inicial
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {

  await axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'minha_url',
    data: {},
  }).then((result) => {
    res.json(result.data); // retorno da api
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/784611/4551469

Comment: a questão não é remover ou substituir por outro caracter e sim trazer o valor correto desses simbolos estranhos...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seu problema está na falta de configuração do axios em relação ao UTF8, encontrei um erro parecido com o seu neste link [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19339069/how-to-encode-http-response-body-as-utf-8-in-node-js) e também neste [inserir a descrição do link aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52863124/how-can-i-get-the-value-in-utf-8-from-an-axios-get-receiving-iso-8859-1-in-node)

Não fiz o teste para saber se funciona, mas parece fazer sentido pelo fato que você precisa configurar o seu sistema para aceitar caracteres especiais

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).